# Symbolic link to my $TMPDIR. Will I break something? (path was too long for emacs)

Tags: macos, emacs, environment-variables, emacs24, tramp

I have rather blindly fixed a problem with a long path to a directory file raising an error in emacs.  Am I going to break something by doing this?  Description of the problem I was solving follows so that if this is a good fix, someone might find it here.

The short of it is that on my Mac OS X Yosemite I did

```
$ cd /var/folders/bh
$ sudo ln -s xqbvhy9j1hg21kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/ tmpd
```

(where /var/folders/bh/xqbvhy9j1hg21kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/ is the value of $TMPDIR)

and then I added this line to ~/.bash_profile

```
export TMPDIR="/var/folders/bh/tmpd/"
```

Will this symbolic link to my TMPDIR break anything?  Will my system override this in the future?

Okay, now for a summary of the problem in Emacs 24.4.1 Cocoa that I had:  I wanted to edit a remote file with C-x C-f

```
/ssh:user@host:/path/to/file
```

and I got an error complaining about the length of my temporary directory, something like "unix_listener, '/var/folders/bh/xqbvhy9j1hg2\
1kb0bh_mm8jc0000gn/T/tramp.47310k2q.%r@%h:%p' too long for Unix domain socket".  I found that this is set by temporary-file-directory, which I figured was just using the environment variable $TMPDIR, which it was, so I introduced the symbolic link and reset the environment variable (customising the variable in emacs didn't seem to work).

Comment: It is hard to think of a question more open-ended than "will X ever break anything?"

Comment: @Chris If you know of something that TMPDIR could break, please mention it.  The openness of "Will X ever break anything?" depends on X, and I have asked the above question with a specific X, that I know little about.  If I knew more about X, I might not have asked the question.  When someone comes along and says "I know about X and I have no idea if that would break anything", we'll call the question unanswerable.

Comment: If I knew something that would break I would have mentioned it. As it happens I have little experience on OSX. But the question *is* extremely broad; IMO too broad for SO. It's also not a programming question, but rather an OSX question. You might have better luck on Super User.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that if the Q. fails to gain traction here.  It's hard to know which of the umpteen dozen SEs to ask on sometimes :(

Comment: You might want to set TMPDIR from within Emacs itself instead; that way, if anything breaks, it will be in Emacs. But [this 4-year-old thread](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29794) seems to suggest it's safe. I wouldn't keep using the tmp dir in /var/folders/whatever; it might change between logins.